# wget gives error "dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libnettle.4.dylib"

Tags: homebrew

When I try to use `wget`, I am getting this error message:

```
$: wget
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libnettle.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/wget
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I have reinstalled `wget` using homebrew (`brew reinstall wget`), I updated and upgraded my homebrew, however this hasn't helped.

In my `/opt/local/lib/` folder I cannot find `libnettle.4.dylib`, however I do find `/opt/local/lib/libnettle.6.dylib`. I tried to solve the problem by simply symlinking from `/opt/local/lib/libnettle.6.dylib` to `/opt/local/lib/libnettle.4.dylib`. This didn't help either, but got me a new error message:

```
$ wget
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libhogweed.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libgnutls.28.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

When I run `brew info wget`, I get this output:

```
wget: stable 1.17.1 (bottled), HEAD
Internet file retriever
https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/
/usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.17.1 (9 files, 1.6M) *
  Built from source with: --with-debug
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/wget.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: xz ✔, pkg-config ✔
Recommended: openssl ✔
Optional: libressl ✔, pcre ✔, libmetalink ✔, gpgme ✔
==> Options
...
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have both [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) and Homebrew installed. MacPorts installs by default in */**opt**/local*, whereas Homebrew installs in */**usr**/local*. Since the command you are actually running is */opt/local/bin/wget*, you probably have */opt/local/bin* before */usr/local/bin* in your PATH environment. Check it with:

`$ echo $PATH`

In such a case, any software installed with Homebrew is not used at all, if not called with its absolute path. So, try launching Homebrew's *wget* with its absolute path:

`$ /usr/local/bin/wget`

If it is working in this way, put */usr/local/bin* as first folder in your PATH environment, by modifying *~/.profile* or *~/.bash_profile* file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved it! Indeed, I had macports installed and it had put /opt/local/bin in the `$PATH`, before '/urs/local/bin'.

Comment: Or use Macports' wget

Answer (score 1):

You could try updating the DYLD cache:

```
sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -root / -force
```

It is possible that the Dynamic Link Library cache hasn't updated to include the shared libraries which were installed when you installed wget.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to run this command, however I got the error message `update_dyld_shared_cache[37979] <Error>: Unable to unlink //var/db/spindump/OLDDSC-1EADBFCB-4F78-34F0-A9C8-F819511098EA: 1 Operation not permitted`. However, the solution by gpz500 worked.

Comment: This worked when I ran *wget --post-data* and got a message about libidn2.0.dylib not being loaded.

Comment: did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

On macports

```
sudo port install wget
```

would install the pcre2 dependency and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the other solutions didn't work for me after I got this error (from a clean Homebrew install):

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/pcre/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/wget
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

However, issuing the following commands (found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50631185/homebrew-will-not-run-wget-command-library-not-loaded) worked fine:

```
brew uninstall --force pcre
brew install pcre
```

Comment: did not work for me